# Program using I/O & Strings. | Basic Inventory Markup Calculator

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, file-io

I am working on writing a program that reads inventory items from a file and adds a markup charge. I am assuming each line will be correct and not using any validation. However, I am building the program on the format of each line HOPEFULLY being: name quantity cost markup.

The cost is the wholesale cost the company paid for the item(per each). The markup is a number between 1 and 100 which indicates the percentage of the markup to determine the retail cost. I'm trying to Output all input data to a file, along with the price, the value of the items wholesale (quantity * cost), the value of the items retail (quantity * price). All currencies should be rounded to two decimals on output (printf). The file should be nicely formatted in tabular form using printf statements for output, and include a title
row.

Currently, I am trying to determine the retail price using a value-returning method and it seems as if I'm missing something? I'm not understanding why even after `outFile.print(Sect[0] + "  " + Sect[1]);` nothing prints to the output file?

### (MY FULL CODE}

```
package pray;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Doitgoooo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int Quantity;
        double Cost, Markup, FinCost=0;
        String Line, item1, item2, item3, item4;
        String[] Sect;
        Scanner inFile;
        PrintWriter outFile;

        System.out.println("(Basic) Inventory Program Starting. Opening file...");
        System.out.println("Please ensure data is entered per line in the format of: 'Name Quantity Cost Markup' ");
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));


        while(inFile.hasNext()){

            Line = inFile.nextLine();
            Sect = Line.split(" ");
            if(Sect.length == 4) {
                item1 = Sect[0];
                item2 = Sect[1];
                item3 = Sect[2];
                item4 = Sect[3];
                Quantity = (int) Double.parseDouble(item2);
                Cost = Double.parseDouble(item3);
                Markup = Double.parseDouble(item4);

                double Value = Quantity * Cost;
                double ValueMarkup = Quantity * FinCost;

                outFile.print(Sect[0] + "  " + Sect[1]);
                outFile.printf("  %.2f  %.2f  %.2f  %.2f %.2f", Cost, Markup, FinCost, Value, ValueMarkup);


            }
            else {
                outFile.println("Line did not have 4 item(s)");
            }
        }
    }

            private void CalculateRetail(double Cost, double Markup) {

                double MarkPerct = Markup/100;
                double MarkAdd = MarkPerct * Cost;
                double FinCost = MarkAdd + Cost;


            }

}
```

### {INPUT EXAMPLE}

thingy 22 15.65 45.00

Whatchacallit 59 67.99 25.5

gizmo 10 100.00 40.00

### {OUTPUT EXAMPLE(NOT WHAT IS PRINTING THIS IS WHAT I AM GOING FOR)}

Item | Quantity | Cost | Markup % | Price(R)| Value (W) | Value (R)

thingy | 22 | 15.65 | 45.00 | 22.69 | 344.30 | 499.24

Whatchacallit | 59 | 67.99 | 25.50 | 85.33 | 4011.41 | 5034.32

gizmo | 10 | 100.00 | 40.00 | 140.00 | 1000.00 | 1400.00

Comment: FYI, Java variables should begin in lowercase.

Comment: can we see at least some of input.txt? your output.txt might help too

Comment: @Justin Edited it and added a sample output file of what I am going for. Thank you and sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program using I/O. | Basic Inventory Markup Calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53716185/program-using-i-o-basic-inventory-markup-calculator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is all your code, then you need to flush and / or close the file to get the data written to the disk.

Add outFile.close() in your code when you are done writing.

Comment: Thank you, Secondly, would you have any ideas on how I can get this program to run the `private void CalculateRetail(double Cost, double Markup) {` method?